# How to aggregate average in MongoDB and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to create aggregation to calculate average for every collection that I have in MongoDB.

I'm getting data from Binance API and storing it inside a MongoDB.

How I can fix that error?

Goal: Calculate average for every different collection.
**Here is the aggregation part of code**

```
const symbols = ["ADABTC", "AEBTC", "AIONBTC", "ALGOBTC", "ARDRBTC"];

const saveToDatebase = async(symbol, BTCdata) => {

const url = 'mongodb://username:password@ip.adress.com/port?<dbname>retryWrites=true&w=majority';
let dateTime = getDateTime();

let db = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
const dbo = db.db('Crypto');
const myobj = Object.assign({ Name: symbol, Date: dateTime }, BTCdata[0]);
await dbo.collection(symbol).insertOne(myobj);
const average = dbo.collection(symbol).aggregate({
    '$group': {
        _id: null,
        'Volume': {
            '$avg': '$Volume'
        }
    }
});
console.log('1 document inserted');
console.log(average);
db.close();
};
```

I receive a huge error in my terminal (Check screenshot)[image]

**Full Code Example**

```
    const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const symbols = ["ADABTC", "AEBTC", "AIONBTC", "ALGOBTC", "ARDRBTC"];

//a descriptive name helps your future self and others understand code easier
const getBTCData = async symbol => { //make this function accept the current symbol
    //async/await lets us write this much nicer and with less nested indents
    let data = await fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbol}&interval=30m&limit=1`).then(res => res.json());
    const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
        return {
            Open: parseFloat(d[1]),
            High: parseFloat(d[2]),
            Low: parseFloat(d[3]),
            Close: parseFloat(d[4]),
            Volume: parseFloat(d[5]),
            Timespan: 30,
        }
    });
    console.log(btcusdtdata);
    saveToDatebase(symbol, btcusdtdata);
};

const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

const j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * * *', async() => {
    for (let symbol of symbols) {
        //we can pass symbol to getBTCData instead of making it
        //responsible for figuring out which symbol it should get
        await getBTCData(symbol);
        await sleep(8000);
    }
});

const getDateTime = () => {
    let today = new Date();
    let date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
    let time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    return date + ' ' + time;
};

const saveToDatebase = async(symbol, BTCdata) => {

    const url = 'mongodb://username:password@server.ip/port?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
    let dateTime = getDateTime();

    let db = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
    const dbo = db.db('Crypto');
    const myobj = Object.assign({ Name: symbol, Date: dateTime }, BTCdata[0]);
    await dbo.collection(symbol).insertOne(myobj);
    const average = dbo.collection(symbol).aggregate({
        '$group': {
            _id: null,
            'Volume': {
                '$avg': '$Volume'
            }
        }
    });
    console.log('1 document inserted');
    console.log(average);
    db.close();
};
```

**EDIT1**

Adding `await` > `const average = await dbo.collection(symbol).aggregate([{`

Doesn't fix a problem.

Comment: if you exclude this function: `const average = dbo.collection(symbol).aggregate({group stage here});` does you `saveToDatebase()` works nice?

Comment: Does you store data for every symbol in separate different collections?

Comment: @AlexZeDim Yes, it works fine. Without any problem.

Comment: @AlexZeDim Yes, I'm storing the data for every symbol in separate different collections.

Comment: That screenshot doesn't look like an error to me.  It looks a lot like a cursor.  Have you tried to iterate the cursor or call the `.toArray` method on it?

Comment: @joe Nope, I didin't. If you know how I can fix this one, that my terminal can show me the average. Cause I really don't understand what is this cursor about.

Comment: `const average = await dbo.collection(symbol).aggregate([{...}]).toArray();` Try this out.

Comment: @ambianBeing and this was the solution. Thank you so much. Can you create an answer that I can upvote and confirm it, please.

Comment: @Joe You was right as well.

Comment: That's kind weird, because `.toArray` working only with cursors, according to documents (http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/AggregationCursor.html#toArray) not queries.

Anyway, everyone answering deserves a credit for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshot doesn't show an error, it shows an [AggregationCursor](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/AggregationCursor.html).

To retrieve the result documents, you will need to call one of the methods of that object, such as [.next()](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/AggregationCursor.html#next) or [.toArray()](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/AggregationCursor.html#toArray).  Most of these return a promise if no callback is passed, so you would need to use await.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the pipeline stages appear in an array in the aggregate method?

```
aggregate([{
        '$group': {
            _id: null,
            'Volume': {
                '$avg': '$Volume'
            }
        }
    }])
```

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I don't understand your post. I literally have the same code as you write here

Comment: @Hexycode If  you look carefully, i am passing an array to the aggregate method rather than an object

Answer (score 0):

How it's relevant to me, lets fix minor errors, and get straight to the point.

`saveToDatebase` should be `saveToDatabase` I guess, it's a grammar error, but it's for you to decide for refactoring.

The second this is, you should use `try/catch` block inside your `async` function, like this:

```
const saveToDatebase = async(symbol, BTCdata) => {
    try { 
      const url = 'mongodb://username:password@server.ip/port?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
      let dateTime = getDateTime();
      let db = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
      const dbo = db.db('Crypto');
      const myobj = Object.assign({ Name: symbol, Date: dateTime }, BTCdata[0]);
      await dbo.collection(symbol).insertOne(myobj);
      const average = dbo.collection(symbol).aggregate([{
        '$group': {
            _id: null,
            'Volume': {
                '$avg': '$Volume'
            }
        }
      }]);
      console.log('1 document inserted');
      console.log(average);
      db.close();
    } catch (e) {
       console.error(e)
    }
};
```

Cause you are using node.js (according to question's tags), not **Deno**

If your problem is relevant with `$group` stage, it could be here:

```
   '$group': {
     _id: null,
     'Volume': {
        '$avg': '$Volume'
      }
```

also, try to use this code at `$group` stage:

```
   "$group": {
     _id: "$_id",
     test: {
        "$avg": "$Volume"
      }
```

You are trying to `$group`, but I am not sure that aggregation framework of MongoDriver (default version of it, not `mongoose`) really takes all document from the collection, try to remove `$group` stage for now, and add `$match`, and take a look, just your `$match` stage takes all DB documents for your collection, and if it does, then add `$group` stage.

The second thing could be:
*I am not sure about it, but have a look*

try to add `await` word before aggregation framework:
`const average = await dbo.collection(symbol).aggregate({`

and make sure that aggregation function executes before the connection with database will be closed by `db.close();`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just tried your methods and I receive same big error in my terminal. I don't receive a print in console of average.

Comment: @Hexycode let's solve it then, edit an original question with your collection's schema and add some example docs at mongoplayground (https://mongoplayground.net/) and share it via link, so I could prove you a working example with `$group`: `$avg` stage.

Answer (score 0):

Put `await` infront of  `dbo.collection(symbol).aggregate({`

`const average = await dbo.collection(symbol).aggregate({`

Comment: @lfaruki Thanks for answer! Unfortunately this doesnt work for me. Having the same problem